# Iphone Message App like textField

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, styling

I was trying to style my iphone app's textfield like the one in the messaging app. I could not style the textfield to have shadow like the messaging app. Messaging app has a shadow that drops inside and has a gradient. How do I do that? Also, setting the clipsToBounds property to yes doesn't let shadow appear. But, not enabling that pushes the text out of the bounds of the textField. How do I handle that?

How do I emulate these behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a UITableView with custom UITableViewCells - that would allow you to tweak the look to your heart's content (specifically, it sounds like you want a cell with a custom background, and a transparent UITextField (without border) positioned within the cell.

Comment: You mean I need to add the UITextField as a subview of some parent view, which I ll style. However, this is not trivial as well. How do I draw a custom border around the transparent UITextField?

Comment: You may need to use some tricks to get the look you want - create a correctly sized UIImageView (that has the border you want) and then place a borderless UITextField within that (as a subview). Sometimes getting the exact look you want (even if it mimics an Apple style) can take a bit of effort and smoke and mirrors ;-)